# How to back up a Windows Home Server over the network?

Tags: backup, networking, external-hard-drive, windows-home-server, iscsi

One of the very few reasons I have to physically interact with my Windows Home Server is to back it up to an external hard drive, with the "Backup Server" feature.

It would be more convenient to plug the external drive in to a desktop PC, and then do the backup over the network.

Is there a way to do this?

I've heard a little about iSCSI, but as far as I can tell it costs money, and I'm hoping for something free.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [Crashplan](https://crashplan.zendesk.com/entries/22224-crashplan-support-for-microsoft-windows-home-server) offers that kind of feature for free.

Comment: Can you quote where they say that they offer that?